# Is it possible to create a read-only System Administrator profile?

Tags: profile, user, roles

I'm in a need to provide create a profile that has full system administrator privileges, but in read-only mode. Is it possible? Use case being, the user will have access to everything such as objects, fields, workflows, email templates - but everything should be read-only.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The important part to think about here is License Type. System Administrator is "Salesforce" License type and if you clone the profile and create new profile with SAME License Type of "Salesforce" then they share same set of features and access to objects etc.

I would suggest you to go for a Clone on existing System Administrator profile and create new Custom System Administrator profile from it. And then in this custom profile make all Fields/objects as readonly/view only for objects that you desire.

Comment: I understand that - what settings control "create validation rules", "create workflow", "create custom object", "pages", etc...

Comment: I tried giving "View All" and "Read" access only - but they are still able to go to Setup -> Customize -> Leads -> Fields and make changes to the Object.

Comment: Found a solution. It's just set of check boxes in Profile under "System Permissions"

Comment: glad you worked it out :-)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to clone a System Admin profile here and make sure you do not give "Modify All Data" privilege to the new profile. 
Also ensure you remove all create, edit, delete permission from Objects ( Standard, Custom ) assuming you want this profile user to view only. 
 Additionally, check the layouts and view for granting Read only access.